# Include all files when debugging in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, file-not-found

How do I setup Visual Studio 2008 to include all files in the project root when debugging?

I have a few files in the project root folder which are not copied to the bin/debug folder so when I am about to debug the application I have to **manually** copy the files. I'm looking for a way to make VS **automatically** include these files in the debug build process. Any hints?

Thank you. /Adam

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For non-source and non-resource files (so are not part of the compilation), set the "Copy To Output Directory" setting in that file's properties to something other than "Do Not Copy".

Answer (score 3):

Try to include the files into the solution and once they appear in your project's tree, set the "Copy to Output Directory" property to one of "Copy always" or "Copy if newer"

Answer (score 0):

I find it easiest to keep them in the bin folder, but add them as to the solution as solution items. That way they're part of the solution, kept under source control, etc., but are always in the right place when you need them at runtime.